# Understanding "Cracker"

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding, irish-english

What does "cracker" mean in these passages  from The Ferryman by Jez Butterworth:

1:
QUINN. Where’s Michael?
CAITLIN. Flat on his cracker in bed.

2:
MICHAEL. Morning, Tom Kettle. Where’s m’da?
CAITLIN. Out in the black barn. Killing the goose.
MICHAEL. I’m s’posed to be killing the goose!
CAITLIN. Not flat on your cracker in bed you’re not. It’s gone six.

Comment: Are you *sure* you've transcribed this accurately? Google has just **3** instances of "out in the **black** barn" (one being this very question, the others clearly not relevant), whereas "out in the **back** barn" gets over 8000 hits. I think it's pretty obvious the intended *meaning* of *on your **cracker*** here is *on your **back*** (or more coarsely, ***backside, arse***), but I've never heard of that usage. As slang, a ***cracker*** is something really good - which I think the specifically *Irish* term ***craic*** derives from (Caitlin being an Irish name).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Reinstate Monica it's from The Farryman by Jez Butterworth

Comment: Ah, so there's definitely an Irish connection. Jez Butterworth is English, but I see that play centres on the IRA hunger strikes. I googled **irish slang cracker ass** and came up with [this.](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/how-to-spell-the-word-craic-or-crack-and-what-shakespeare-would-have-said-1.3893443) News to me, but apparently Shakespeare has the line *What cracker is this same that deafs our ears / With this abundance of superfluous breath?* (which I understand as *Who farted?*). A bit tenuous, but *maybe* that eventually led to the usage here. It's certainly not "common" though.